# What bitrate can I expect with MPEG?

Tags: video, encoding, mpeg, bitrate

What bit-rate (approximately) can I expect MPEG encoders to produce for 160x120 "ok-quality" webcam stream?

How much CPU-demanding will the encoding be? The decoding?

Are there any better encoding formats for that purpose? (In terms of bit-rate or CPU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`256 KBps` is enough for `QSIF` (`160x120`, `25 fps`) in `MPEG2`.

Any modern `CPU` (since `Pentium IV`) can encode and decode it in realtime.

There are hardware solutions (like `Compro VideoMate` `H900` and `E800` series), which cost about `100$` and up to `8` boards can be installed per `PC`.

Using them, you can get `8` full-size streams at once, to say nothing of `QSIF`.

`MPEG4` can probably yield better results in terms of bandwidth, but it's more sensitive to the packet drops in the channel.

As for the sound, if you need telephony quality, you can use `aLaw` or `uLaw` codec, which require `64 kbps` per channel and are not a problem even for a `Casio` calculator.